# Problema matriz c# seleccionar parejas

Tags: c#

Antes de nada explicar que el "ejercicio" que intento hacer es un pequeño juego de parejas, en el que introduces unas coordenadas y se te muestra el valor albergado en dicha coordenada. En el momento que dos de los valores de las coordenadas que has metido son iguales (por ejemplo, meto (0,1) y me sale 3, luego meto (2,4) y me sale 3. Si me saliese 4 volvería a pedirme coordenadas para los dos valores) debería salir del do[...]while.
Tengo el siguiente problema y que por más que le doy vueltas no consigo resolver:

Al seleccionar un número de dentro de la matriz, se me queda guardado y no consigo que a la segunda vez que introduzco los números cambie el valor que tengo que sacar de la matriz. Me imprime solo el primer número, el segundo nunca, me lo copia del primero.

La variable "sig" no está en uso para comprobar que los números que se escogen de la matriz son diferentes.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] matriz2 = new int[5, 5];           
        Random ale = new Random();
        bool acierto = false;
        int guardo = 0, guardo2 = 16;
        int intentos = 0;
        string sig = "?";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                matriz2[i, j] = ale.Next(0, 11);
                Console.Write("\t{0}", matriz2[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }         
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca las coordenadas.");
            int numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Mostramos el valor: ");
            Console.WriteLine(funcion1(matriz2, numero, numero2));
            guardo = matriz2[numero, numero2];  
            if (guardo == guardo2)
                acierto = true;
            guardo2 = guardo;
            intentos++;
        } while (acierto != true);
        Console.Read();

    }
    static int funcion1(int[,] ar, int num1, int num2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                ar[i, j] = ar[num1, num2];
            }
        }
        return ar[num1, num2];
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganes tu primera medalla. También es importante leer [ask] para aprender a hacer una buena pregunta. He releido tu pregunta varias veces, he visto el código y todavía no se que es lo que intentas. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y explicar brevemente que intentas conseguir? Para que tienes una variable `matriz` si luego no la utilizas nunca?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la función `funcion1`.

No sé qué pretendes hacer exactamente en esa función pero lo que está haciendo realmente es asignar el valor del elemento seleccionado (`ar[num1, num2]`) a todas las posiciones del array. Con lo que el array queda con todos los números iguales. Por eso devuelve una y otra vez el mismo número.

En realidad podrías simplemente devolver el valor directamente del array. Como decía: no sé qué intentas hacer exactamente con esa función:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int[,] matriz2 = new int[5, 5];
    Random ale = new Random();
    bool acierto = false;
    int guardo = 0, guardo2 = 16;
    int intentos = 0;
    string sig = "?";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            matriz2[i, j] = ale.Next(0, 11);
            Console.Write("\t{0}", matriz2[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Introduzca las coordenadas.");
        int numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Mostramos el valor: ");
        Console.WriteLine(matriz2[ numero, numero2]);
        guardo = matriz2[numero, numero2];
        if (guardo == guardo2)
            acierto = true;
        guardo2 = guardo;
        intentos++;
    } while (acierto != true);
    Console.Read();

}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Pues está visto que me lié con la función esa, porque creía que hacía otra cosa. Un saludo :D.

Answer (score 0):

Primero no se por que inicias la variable a 16, prueba a ñadir como te he añadido yo una sentencia else, para que no te haga la misma asignacion siempre, deberia asi funcionar

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] matriz2 = new int[5, 5];           
        Random ale = new Random();
        bool acierto = false;
        int guardo = 0;
        int guardo2 = 0;
        int intentos = 0;
        string sig = "?";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                matriz2[i, j] = ale.Next(0, 11);
                Console.Write("\t{0}", matriz2[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }         
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduzca las coordenadas.");
            int numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Mostramos el valor: ");
            Console.WriteLine(funcion1(matriz2, numero, numero2));
            guardo = matriz2[numero, numero2];  
            if (guardo == guardo2){
                acierto = true;
            }else{
            guardo2 = guardo;
            intentos++;
            }
        } while (acierto != true);
        Console.Read();

    }
    static int funcion1(int[,] ar, int num1, int num2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                ar[i, j] = ar[num1, num2];
            }
        }
        return ar[num1, num2];
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Acabo de probarlo y sigue sin funcionar, o sea, funciona pero igual que antes. Lo inicializaba a 16 porque esta fuera del rango 0-10, al tenerla a 0 al principio a veces cuando seleccionaba coordenadas en las que había un 0 el programa fallaba y no me dejaba introducir las segundas coordenadas.